# Problems decoding printed bytearray

Tags: java

I am printing a byte array of image in my code.
I am trying to debug it by printing it but this is the output i am seeing in console-

03-02 13:49:03.764  25818-25848/com.example.listviewandroid I/System.out﹕ [B@41484350tehe repub size: 0

What does this mean? is it getting the byte array here or what?

```
public void getImage(byte[] data) {
        try
        {
            imagedata = data;
            System.out.print(data);
//        imgTakenPhoto.removeAllViews();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            imgTakenPhoto.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            imgTakenPhoto.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {}

    }
```

I am trying to find out what is in "Data" here

Comment: code example of what are you printing?

Comment: It means that Java has used it's default `toString` method to represent the array...not it's contents.  You might consider using `Arrays.toString(...)` instead

Comment: And? As I said, if you want to see the actual data, you want to use something like `System.out.print(Arrays.toString(data));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you copy the REFERENCE to your byte array from data to imagedata : `imagedata = data;`

Using this : `System.out.print(data);` will use toString() method, which contains - if not overriden - class of instance and its reference (its address to memory)

You want this : `System.out.print(Arrays.toString(data))`

---

Also important note, when I talked about copying reference in `imagedata = data`, it means, that both variables pointing to the same array. If you do something like `data[5] = 4`, variable `imagedata[4]` will contain 4